# Flutter firebase: Create multiple collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to create a multiple documents in the same collection? If yes, how do you do that?

for example there is a main collection `POST`.
In this `POST` collection the user creates multiple posts.

POST - [post1], [post2],[post3] etc

Comment: Sure, send them as an array of objects instead of a single object to your POST function, and there just loop over each object, adding them one by one. But it's easier if you can show your actual code so we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you, but can you reference me to a link or give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase documentation shows how to [add a document to a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). If you want to add multiple documents to a collection, you can repeat that code multiple times.

If you want to add multiple documents atomically, you can [use a batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank van Puffelen. Could u please work on this problem for me..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75835521/flutter-firebase-update-field-in-sub-collection